# Progress bar on Powershell script

Tags: powershell

Is there any way to have a progress bar when copying files on PowerShell scripts?

I didn't have any progress trying `Write-Progress`

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-progress?view=powershell-7.2 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5862396/powershell-get-childitem-progress-question

Comment: Thank you @VomitIT-ChunkyMessStyle

Comment: Please show what you've tried with Write-Progress.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried **Start-BitsTransfer**?

**Example:**

Start-BitsTransfer -Source C:\Backups*.mdb -Destination S:\MyDestinationPath\

**More info:**

```
Get-Help Start-BitsTransfer
```

**Get more examples:**

```
Get-Help Start-BitsTransfer -Examples
```

**Online:** https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/bitstransfer/start-bitstransfer?view=windowsserver2019-ps